# Searching Dates and Ignoring time and date in mongoDB node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, date

I am using node.js and monodb database where I want to query records based on date and I want to ignore time and date only month and year will be matched here is my code:-

```
  collection.find({ date: { "$gte": sDate, "$lt": eDate) } }).count(function (e, c) {
 });
```

this is working but matching date and time as well how I can match only month and year? Please help me to solve this problem.

Edit:- some data from collection:-

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5535e76f82a964d011e34fcf"),
"VisitorId" : "5535e72a82a964d011e34fcb",    
"date" : ISODate("2015-01-21T06:00:15.761Z"),
}

{
"_id" : ObjectId("5535e75f82a964d011e34fcf"),
"VisitorId" : "5535e72a82a964d011e34fcb",    
"date" : ISODate("2015-04-21T06:00:15.761Z"),
}
```

I will pass two params i.e {month:"1",year:"2015"};

and in output first docs should be display.

Thanks

Comment: @JohnnyHK thanks,  i have add some sample data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the [**`$where`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/where/) operator in your query:

```
collection.find({
    "$where": function() { 
        return this.date.getMonth() == 0 && this.date.getFullYear() == 2015
    } 
}).count(function (err, data) {
   // Handle err
});
```

However, query performance is rather compromised because using [**`$where`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/where/)  alone requires a table scan, it takes a global lock. You should use [**`$where`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/where/) only when you can't express your query using another operator. If you must use [**`$where`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/where/) , try to include at least one other standard query operator to filter the result set.

Other options are to modify your schema and store the month in its own property (if it's a common field in your queries). You are guaranteed better query performance since the field can be indexed.

The other option will be when query a specific month and year, create a query object that only looks for the start and the end of that specific month.

```
var sDate = new Date(2015, 0, 1);
var eDate = new Date(2015, 1, 1);

collection.find({ date: { "$gte": sDate, "$lt": eDate) } }).count(function (e, c) {
 });
```

Comment: thanks for your first solution that worked form me and i can't use second option.

Comment: i also found this solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26308525/searching-dates-and-ignoring-time-in-mongodb which also worked  is it better than $where condition
? should i use that?

Comment: @user3819192 I don't know how these two methods fare in terms of performance but using the `$where` operator alone is generally discouraged because of slow performance and global locks.